# What is DISK=/dev/sdX?

Tags: sd-card, beagleboard

I am following this [link](https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-SetupmicroSDcard)
 to create a bootable SD card.  I am stuck at `mkfs.ext4 <= 1.42`.

```
for: DISK=/dev/mmcblk0
```

The terminal complains that no 'for' command is found.  I suppose I should leave 'for' out?  Next:

```
for: DISK=/dev/sdX
sudo mount ${DISK}1 /media/rootfs/
```

The terminal throws this error:

```
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The file /dev/sdX1 does not exist and no size was specified.
```

What am I doing wrong?  Also, how can I have mke2fs updated to mke2fs 1.43-WIP (15-Mar-2016)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines "for: DISK=/dev/mmcblk0" and "for: DISK=/dev/sdX" are for your eyes only, not command lines. "for:"only points to the following instructions in the [tutorial](https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-SetupmicroSDcard), which are command lines and should be run.

---

The following command lines set the environment variable `DISK`

- for a card connected via a PCI card reader

  ```
  DISK=/dev/mmcblk0
  ```
- for a card connected via a USB card reader,

  ```
  DISK=/dev/sdX
  ```

  In this case you should **replace `X` with the actual drive letter** (`a`, `b`, `c` ...), so **for example `/dev/sdb`**, that you can identify with the commands

  ```
  sudo lsblk --fs     # Output info about filesystems
  sudo lsblk --perms  # Output info about device owner, group and mode
  sudo parted -ls     # --list: lists partition layout on all block devices; --script: never prompts for user intervention
  ```

  In general, you can use the commands above to find out how the card is connected and identified.

This environment variable is used in the next command in the [tutorial](https://eewiki.net/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-SetupmicroSDcard) as `${DISK}`, for example (depending on the version of `mkfs.ext4`),

- when connected via PCI

  ```
  sudo mkfs.ext4 -L rootfs -O ^metadata_csum,^64bit ${DISK}p1
  ```
- or when connected via USB

  ```
  sudo mkfs.ext4 -L rootfs -O ^metadata_csum,^64bit ${DISK}1
  ```

`${DISK}p1` and `${DISK}1` specify the *partition* where you want to create an `ext4` file system.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I wish the documentation can be that clear.

Comment: @CaTx, You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

`For` is not a command, he is giving examples for two different partition labels since /sdX and /mmcblk have different notations for partitions.

sdX is a generic notation for a block device (HDD, SSD, USB). The "X" is replaced by a letter that is determined by the order in which the device was mounted.

Change the generic statements he uses for the specific information from your system. Use `lsblk` to find the label linux is using for your SDcard. Then use that in the statement `DISK=`.

Examples:

```
DISK=/dev/sdb -- partition=/dev/sdb1
```

or

```
DISK=/dev/mmcblk0 -- partition=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using for:  try using `export` command and to the mounting part , like Cornea Valentin said , check if your target is detected by using

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0
```

If detected and still there is problem during mounting try this :

```
sudo mount -v -t ext4 /dev/mmcblk0 /media/rootfs
```

Answer (score -1):

check if target really exist with **fdisk** or **gparted**

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

gparted must be installed:

```
sudo apt install gparted
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the two commands could help OP solving the question ?

Comment: well from what he said up there he try to mount nonexistent partition and with fdisk/lsblk/gparted  he can see all partition from pc.